# TimeInterval calculation issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, time, nsdate

I am trying to create an app that calculates the time difference and the amount is multiplied by an amount in money. It is targeted to calculate in R$ (brazilian real) the amount that someone will have to pay for using a service during the time calculated by the app.

Here´s is my code:

```
- (IBAction)encerrar:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
    NSString *temp = inicio.text;
    NSDate *then = [dateFormatter dateFromString:temp];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:then];
    NSString *ext = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    fim.text = ext;
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    duracao.text = timeString;

    double timeIntervalInHours = (timeInterval / 3600.0) * 5;        

    NSString *vTotal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"R$ %.2f", fecha];
    NSLog(@"%.2f", timeIntervalInHours);
    vlrTotal.text = vTotal;
}
```

The fact is that when we click on Calculate button, and if the duracao (duration) is equal to 1h it gives me the correct amount which is R$ 5,00. But when the duration is equal to 30mins or other value different from exact 1h, it gives the wrong amount.

I.E.: 1h should be R$ 5,00; while 1:30h should be R$ 7,50, but shows me R$ 6,50.

So, anyone could help me on this???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hint: 1.3*5 = 6.5. You're calculating 30min as 3/10 of an hour instead as 1/2 of an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeInterval` is the amount of time in seconds, so if you want it in hours and fractions of an hour just do this:

```
double timeIntervalInHours = timeInterval / 3600.0;
```

and then multiple `timeIntervalInHours` times the price/hour to get the cost.

**EDIT**
Based on our chat, I would create a button with "iniciar" (start) as the title.  When they press that button, I would store the current time and change the title to "encerrar" (stop). (I hope that my translations are correct, lol)  Then the button action would look something like this:

```
// self.startTime is a NSDate.
- (IBAction)iniciar_encerrar:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"iniciar"]) {
        // We are starting the time
        if (self.startTime != nil) {
            return;
        }

        self.startTime = [NSDate date];
        [sender setTitle:@"encerrar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        // We are stopping the time
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeInSeconds = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
        double cost = elapsedTimeInSeconds / 3600.0 * 5.0;
        NSLog(@"%.2lf", cost);

        // reset the button
        self.startTime = nil;
        [sender setTitle:@"iniciar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

**startTime is declared as follows:**

In your .h file, along with the other declared properties, add:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startTime;
```

In your .m file, add this at the top with the other ones:

```
@synthesize startTime;
```

In your `viewDidUnload` function (in your .m file) add this:

```
startTime = nil;
```

This just gives you a place to store the startTime date.

Comment: It really should.  What result did you get?

Comment: I did this: double timeIntervalInHours = (timeInterval / 3600.0) * 5; but i get this 'R$ 1851965.02' for calculating a one hour duration and it should be R$ 5.00

Comment: It probably came out to a whole number when it converted. (I assumed that your amount was a float or double). I updated the code for you to fix that.

Comment: If the time difference is 1h timeInterval gives me: 1333414840.60

Comment: "then" is just setting a time with no date and then comparing it to today's date.  This will result in an extremely long timeInterval (from 1970 to now! )

Comment: Ok, agree, but why I am getting this error?? I checked the code many many times but can´t figure where the problem is.

Comment: I edited the question with my actual code that gives me the incorrect timInterval amount.

Comment: What date is "then" supposed to represent?

Comment: 'then' is entered through a text field.

Comment: 'then' is the start time and now the end time. And the user inputs just the time, not the date, like 17:45.

Comment: Do you want to assume that it is 1745 in today's date then?  What if the time is earlier than the current time?  Assume tomorrow?

Comment: Well, I didn´t understand your question. What it happens is that, there´s a text field. The user inputs a time, like 13:00. In code, it will convert the NSString named 'temp' (which holds the user input), into a NSDate named 'then'. After some time passed, the user finishes and clicks 'Calcular' button which executes the 'encerrar' action. Doing so, it will create NSDate 'now' the current time, and then calculate the difference through timeInterval. Basically this is how I wanted to happen.

Comment: Also, the end time will always be the current time and the start time will always be a time earlier then the end time.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that "13:00" is just a time without a date.  In order to use `[now timeIntervalSinceDate:then]` you must set date to a time **and** a date so that it is a specific point in time.  Let's say that it is 16:00 right now.  If they enter 13:00 do you want the starting time to be "April 3rd 2012 13:00"?  What if they enter 17:00?  Should it be "April 2nd 2012 17:00" to make it in the past?  Or should that be an error?

Comment: Ohh i got it. then must be today too, like: 'then' (user input) should be 16:00 april 3rd 2012, and after some time, after clicking on the button and triggering the action, 'now' should be 17:00 april 3rd 2012. Is there a  way the user can input just the time and in code it generates the complete date using the time the user input?

Comment: I'm confused.  If it is 16:00 right now and they enter 13:00 then "then" should be 13:00 april 3rd 2012, right?  And if they enter 17:00 we should change it to be 16:00 april 3rd 2012?

Comment: Nope. Let me explain better my project.. The app should work like a cybercafe/lanhouse administrator. When someone start using a pc I will input the start time and won´t click the button yet. But when the user finishes using the pc and come to the cashier to pay, then I will click the Calcular button and trigger the whole stuff and pick the current time and set to 'now' and make the calculation. Got it now?

Comment: Okay, so `inicio.text` will not be entered directly by the user and there is no possibility of it being later than the current time?  This is still problematic though if the time passes midnight between the start and end times.  You really need to store the `[NSDate date]` value of the start time instead of just a string showing the time.  Then you can calculate the time interval between the two times (no matter what kind of time changes, etc there are) and it will give the correct number of seconds between the start and end times.

Comment: Well, since the lanhouse work hours are not beyond 10pm there won´t be that problem. But since you told me that I had to add also a date not only a time, do you think I would solve this whole problem if I implmented sometinhg like: instead of inputing just the time, the user would touch the screen where input time should be and then a datepicker would popover configured just to show the time, then the user would select and I would have showing on screen just the time, but in code I would have the complete date and time needed?? What do you think??

Comment: Not knowing anything else about your app, my first thought would be to just have a button that says "Start" and set the current date & time in the button action with `self.startTime = [NSDate date];`.  You can display that value in a label or something if you want them to see it.  (You probably also want to make sure that if there is already a value there it doesn't over-write it so that they can't "re-start" the time at some later point).

Comment: Humm, that´s a good suggestion. I´ll try mine and yours and post here the results, or doubts. Thank very much for helping Inafziger.

Comment: Please see my updated code.  Note that you would probably want to "lock" the start-stop button after they stop the first time so that they can't stop and re-start the timer to save money.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the code!!! But I am getting this error: Property 'startTime' not found on object of type 'ViewController *' every line I have the self.startTime. I am using xcode 4.3, ios 5.1

Comment: You need to declare it in your .h file and synthesize it in your .m file.

Comment: Fixed that issue but got another one. The app is crashing and console gives me: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x6883940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'

Comment: Yes instead of id I used UIButton.

Comment: Okay, but the actual objects (in interface builder) is a UIButton?

Comment: Yes it is. Also im using storyboard, ok?

Comment: Must to say that now is working, dont know what happened, but after I restarted my mac everyhting worked just fine. Finally got it working and solved my problem which really was I just set the time (hour and minutes) but I need also to set the date. Thank you very much Inafziger! Best regards!

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer as the correct one by clicking the check mark at the top left of the question so that is get credit for my help then!

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the time string HHmm to a float, so at 1.5 hours, you will have a float of 130 (1 hour 30 min). I can't follow your calculations from there. I think what you want is to have two formatters, one to get minutes, and one for hours, like so:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"HH";
float hours = [[formatter stringFromDate:timerDate] intValue] * 1.0;
formatter.dateFormat = @"mm";
hours += [[formatter stringFromDate:timerDate] intValue]/60.0; //convert min to fractional hours and add
```

Comment: Or just do everything in minutes and write a method to convert minutes-to-hours (hours to minutes would obviously be trivial).

Comment: Well, basically the problem is that when I convert the time difference into string it gives me 0130 for 01:30h and like Michael noted, if I calculate using 0130 is not the same as 1.50 which would be one hour and a half in numbers. The problem is that I don´t know how to code and make 0130 or other time different from 0100, equal to 1.50

Comment: I think it would solve if I could get the timeinterval in minutes, which I don´t know how to do.

Comment: Just use the code snip above. That gives you hours as 1.5 for an hour and a half. If you want minutes, just multiply by 60.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida: try modified version. Adam, hope you don't mind me modifying your code a bit

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the amount $R5,00 from an hourly amount to an amount per second for better accuracy. 5/ 60 minutes / 60 seconds gives you .00388889 which you would multiply by (duration*1000) to give you your accurate result.

Comment: Cliff I did this, but didn´t work:

    
    
    double fecha = (timeInterval * 1000) * 0.00388889;
      
    

All I get is a long number and not the correct amount.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a 1, the number is 0.001388889. Let's take your original math time (interval / 3600) * 5, which gives you the correct amount per hour. That means timeInterval is in seconds. (I was assuming milliseconds earlier.) 5/3600 gives you 0.001388889 per second. So your final calc should be $RperSecond = timeInterval * 0.001388889.

Comment: Odd, make sure RPerSecond is declared as a double. I don't understand how you could get the same answer with a different calculation using different numbers.

Comment: Well, Cliff it seems that the problem is because I didn´t use a complete date as Inafziger pointed at the answer below, check it out, please. And thank you.